# Get Cordova device in GopherJS

Tags: cordova, gopherjs

I'm going through a Cordova tutorial and trying to do the exercises in GopherJS. I installed the "device" plugin (`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device`) and am trying to get the fields of the device:

```
type (
    Info struct {
        *js.Object
        Cordova  string `js:"cordova"`
        Model    string `js:"model"`
        Platform string `js:"platform"`
        Serial   string `js:"serial"`
        UUID     string `js:"uuid"`
        Version  string `js:"version"`
    }
)

var device = &Info{Object: js.Global.Get("device")}
```

but they are empty. How can I read them?
Is there some way to get GopherJS to fill the fields from the `*js.Object`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to wait until the `deviceready` event occurs:

```
var device *Info

// ...
func onDeviceReady(dom.Event) {
    device = &Info{Object: js.Global.Get("device")}
}
```